# Integrating with JFrog XRay

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-xray

On this page: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/XRAY/Integrations, the XRay documentation discusses how to integrate XRay with other third-party vulnerability providers. At the bottom of the page it also talks about how to integrate with a custom provider. But, I can't find any documentation about how to write a service that allows XRay to pull vulnerability data from my service. What interface does it expect from a custom vulnerability provider? Can anyone point me to the appropriate documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is on the page you referred to, under the [Adding a Custom Integration](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/XRAY/Integrations#Integrations-AddingaCustomIntegration) header.

In order to create a custom integration, the REST service you build needs to have two endpoints:

1) `/api/checkauth` (a GET operation to validate a specific API key is valid or not)
2) `<your api path>` (a GET operation to retrieve the actual contents)

For both operations the page lists sample requests and responses.